# How to get products list by products ids in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get woocommerce product list by IDs array i.e. 1001, 1002...

Try to use "post__in" parameter for WP_Query but never got any product from desired IDs array.

This is code I use:

```php
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__in'=> array(1001, 1002)
);
$result = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
$args = array(
    
    'include' => array( 134, 200, 210, 340 ),
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```